# Loading custom classes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm rewriting one old app - Rails 1.2.6 :)) - completely in Rails 4... so you can imagine the information overload.

It's going quite well so far but I'm currently struggling with one task that should be pretty obvious but it lacks proper documentation and there are just too many blogs with different solutions to this issue.

I have a custom class with custom text conversion functionality (using Redcloth, autolinker, Sanitize etc.), let's call it `Textilize` class. It's used in models as well as controllers so I guess the best solution would be to create a gem from it. I want to attack gem creation later though since it's just a simple one-file class.

So for now I just added `textilize.rb` file to /lib directory and added `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`.

It works fine and I can now use it in the app without requiring it in the models and controllers.

Is this a good practice in Rails 4? Is it thread-safe?
If not, is there a way to refactor it without creating a complete gem for now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Is this a good practice?" I think it is.

"Is it thread-safe?" I don't know

Any other way? I will use your solution if the lib is crossing Model and Controller and it is simple. If it get rather complex, I will create a plugin. If it is complex and can be extended to be useful on other apps, I will create a gem.

Comment: plugins are no longer supported in rails 4

Comment: @FrederickCheung, thanks for the info. I havn't worked on a Rails 4 project yet. Just checked and verified that, though 'libs/plugins' can still be used.

Comment: Ah - I thought you mean an actual rails plugin

Comment: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/rails-4-is-thread-safe-by-default-rails-4-countdown-to-2013 @Martin Sojka